# Bug? Errors inside lambda expression in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, lambda, visual-studio-2015

I don't know if this is a bug but back in VS2013 the VB compiler seems to be able to recognize errors inside a lambda expression. While in VS2015 just tells me "something wrong with your sub", not where.

Here are some screenshots.

In VS2013:
[image: Visual Studio 2013]

In VS2015:
[image: Visual Studio 2015]

Looks like the problem only resides in VB compiler.

Comment: I would suggest reporting this to https://connect.microsoft.com/ as there has been several things in VS2015 that were skipped in the re-build of the Roslyn project.

Comment: @KarenPayne I did and they say they are reviewing the issue. Guess I just wait for it then. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, this is the link to the MS site: [Errors inside VB lambda expression in Visual Studio 2015 not recognized](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2416478/errors-inside-vb-lambda-expression-in-visual-studio-2015)